# ffmpeg stuck while attempting to loop video over audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am using the command found here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/ffmpeg-loop-video-to-the-length-of-audio

that is in the edit,

```
ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp4 -c copy -v 0 -f nut - | ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 10K -i - -i 1.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest -y out.mp4
```

And upon executing, it wont output anything at all. It simply gets stuck.

I don't mind if I need to use something else to loop a video over audio (ie, audio = 10 mins, vid = 5 mins, have video repeat once), so if anyone has any idea how to do that (in a way that works) that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ffmpeg **4.1** or newer, use

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp4 -i 1.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest out.mp4
```